# JavaScript to allow either one checkbox or from a group of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have a div with four checkboxes and the user should be allowed to select either the first checkbox or a combination from two, three and four but not together. example scenarios:

1. First checkbox or second checkbox
2. First checkbox or third checkbox
3. First checkbox or fourth checkbox
4. First checkbox or (second and third)
5. First checkbox or (third and fourth)
6. First checkbox or (second and fourth)
7. First checkbox or (second and third and fourth)

The div is something like this:

```
<div class="question" id="someFilters">
    <label>Some Suppliers</label>
        <div class="someclass">
            <form:checkbox id="firstcheckbox" value="First checkbox"/>
                <label class="inputtext">First Checkbox</label>
            <form:checkbox id="secondcheckbox" value="Second checkbox"/>
                <label class="inputtext">Second Checkbox</label>
            <form:checkbox id="thirdcheckbox" value="Third checkbox"/>
                <label class="inputtext">Third Checkbox</label>
            <form:checkbox id="fourthcheckbox" value="Fourth checkbox"/>
                <label class="inputtext">Fourth Checkbox</label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wrote an answer because I had time, but if you're wondering why you're seeing more downvotes than responses, it's likely because your question doesn't show any attempt to find a solution on your own (even if you did make such attempts). See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for the condition you describe is simple:
Either the first box must not be checked or all the other boxes must not be checked.

The variable `valid` in this script will be assigned a boolean value based on whether that condition is met.
This assignment statement works because the variable `cs` has previously been assigned a NodeList containing all the input elements in order (via `.querySelectorAll("input")` -- although you may want to use a selector that targets elements by name or class or some other attribute.)

Note that the html you posted is not properly formatted. Specifically, `<form:checkbox />` does not represent an html element.

```js
const cs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate(){
  const valid = !cs[0].checked || !cs[1].checked && !cs[2].checked && !cs[3].checked;
  console.log(valid ? "good" : "bad");
}
```

```html
  
<input type="checkbox" />1
<input type="checkbox" />2
<input type="checkbox" />3
<input type="checkbox" />4 <br />
<button type="button">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cat, the validation logic helped me solved the issue. Also, your pointers for the downvoting for not showing the effort from my side is noted. Cheers.

Comment: Great. I made a quick edit to my final note about html because I had formatted it wrong. Remember to mark the answer as accepted if you get a chance.